# Convert SRDF to Collada (dae)

Tags: ros, srdf, openrave, collada-urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a robot model in myrobot.urdf and myrobot.srdf. Now I want to use the model in OpenRave, so I need to convert the *rdf files to COLLADA files or OpenRave xml format. With collada_urdf I converted myrobot.urdf into myrobot.dae, but it does not contain the information of manipulators (a.k.a. groups in SRDF), which is crucial for OpenRave to work. I googled a lot on how to convert SRDF to COLLADA but did not found anything. Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261518/convert-srdf-to-collada-(dae)/) by [Xuesong](https://answers.ros.org/users/30342/xuesong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not really conversion per se (ie: I don't think you get the output to store somewhere), but I know of [or_urdf](https://github.com/personalrobotics/or_urdf) which is an OpenRAVE plugin that allows you to load urdfs and srdfs directly into OpenRAVE.

I'm not sure what pieces of an srdf it actually supports. You'll have to check that for yourself.

The Personal Robotics devs have created quite a few interesting OpenRAVE<->ROS integration tools.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xuesong](https://answers.ros.org/users/30342/xuesong/) on 2017-05-11**:
Hi gvdhoorn, I did a quick check on or_urdf. It may not work perfectly for my case (due to the non-perfect mapping between SRDF and OpenRave features), but should be a good start. Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-11**:
Good to hear. Perhaps you can extend `or_urdf` and contribute back to the Personal Robotics ppl? I'm sure they would appreciate that a lot (and so would I).